# Why do existing map services run slow after updating to ArcGIS 10.2.1 for Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, installation

Has anyone had any issues with existing map services after updating to ArcGIS Server 10.2.1?  After updating they are running slow and causing my ArcGIS Javascript app to crash.  All of our GIS services are on 10.2.1 now (Desktop, Server, SDE).

Any ideas?  I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to provide more details of the precise errors and/or symptoms that you are seeing, please?

Comment: We are about to upgrade soon and ESRI advised to recreate the map services after the upgrade.

Comment: I did not have to recreate the service just overwrite the existing service.  This solved our issues.

Comment: Rather than include your resolution as an edit to your Question, I recommend that you post it as a self-Answer and then self-Accept it (which can be done, although not immediately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved it myself. I republished all my map services which took care of the issue.